# "the compiler will set aside 4 bytes for the variable even though the variable itself only requires 1 byte." Is it right?

Tags: c++, operating-system

Here is a `c++` code snippet. It shows the size of an instance of an empty class is `1`.
But here is what I am wondering. If memory alignment is considered and every object or variable is allocated at the memory region that begins at, for example, multiple of 4. Can we say `instance_a` is size of 1 byte but actually occupies 4 bytes(by that I mean the compiler will set aside 4 bytes for the variable even though the variable itself only requires 1 byte), because the tailing 3 bytes will not be part of other variables' memory region(will not be touched by the compiler because most of the time it has a better choice)?

```cpp
class A{};

int main(){
    A instance_a = A();
    cout << sizeof(instance_a) << endl;  // 1
    return 0;
}
```

---

update: I've read the comments. I know the `A[]` array is compact. I agree compiler make the final call. Let's just focus on the object `instance_a` and forget about the `A[]` array. Is it possible that the 3 bytes after `instance_a`(size == 1) will be a part of other object's memory region? I don't think the compiler have a strong reason to touch the tailing 3 bytes, because these bytes are not multiple of 4. If an object begins at one of the 3 bytes, the object is not memory aligned. --- Why would the compiler touch it if it has a better choice?

update2: Thanks JaMiT's comment. My word was not accurate enough. "the compiler will set aside 4 bytes for the variable even though the variable itself only requires 1 byte. " That is what I want to express.

Comment: No, you cannot say anything like that. Your C++ compiler has the final word on how things are to be aligned.

Comment: Does `A a[2];` occupy 2 bytes or 8 bytes or something else?  That's also up to the compiler.

Comment: No.   The compiler *might* allocate more memory than `sizeof` for that type but the standard does not require it to.   Practically, if a struct types alignment requirement is 4 bytes, most current compilers by default will adjust the size of the type to avoid such things (i.e. they place the padding in the type, not after an instance of it).  But, again, that is a choice in the compiler implementation.

Comment: *"If [...] every object or variable is allocated at the memory region that begins at, for example, multiple of 4"* -- If you define `char c[8]`, then each of the eight elements of `c` is an object. So by your assumption, each element of the array would be allocated at a region that begins at a multiple of 4. Typically, a `char` occupies one byte. You wish to assume that there are three bytes between `c[0]` and `c[1]`?

Comment: No, never. A variable occupies memory space *equal* to its size. Whatever extra memory the compiler may require for padding, alignment etc is *not* part of the variable.

Comment: *"Let's just focus on the object `instance_a`"* -- if you want to focus on `instance_a`, maybe you want to edit your question from *"[...] every object or variable is allocated [...]"* to just *"[...] every variable is allocated [...]"*?

Comment: If I understand your intended question, you might want to reconsider your word choice. A variable "occupying" 4 bytes suggests that the variable expands to fill all 4 bytes. I think you mean something more like "consuming" 4 bytes or "requiring" 4 bytes; these are closer to suggesting that the compiler will set aside 4 bytes for the variable even though the variable itself only requires 1 byte. (Or perhaps not try to squeeze all that meaning into one word.)

Comment: @JaMiT Well said. My word was not accurate enough. "the compiler will set aside 4 bytes for the variable even though the variable itself only requires 1 byte. " That is what I want to express.

Answer (score 1):

> Can we say instance_a is size of 1 byte but actually occupies 4 bytes

No.  The amount of memory an object occupies *is* its size.  That may be different from the sum of the sizes of its members, however, even for POD objects. Such differences very often are the result of alignment requirements such as you describe.  Bytes that have no function other than to align members or fill out the object's size to some target value are called "padding".  They are part of the representation of the object.

> Let's just focus on the object instance_a and forget about the A[] array. Is it possible that `instance_a`'s tailing 3 bytes will be a part of other object's memory region?

No. If `instance_a` has size 4 then all four bytes belong to that object.  Some or all may be shared with its members, but none are shared with objects that are not its members, unless `instance_a` is a member of a union.

> My word was not accurate enough. "the compiler will set aside 4 bytes for the variable even though the variable itself only requires 1 byte. "

The compiler will reserve a contiguous region of exactly `sizeof instance_a` bytes for the representation of `instance_a`.  This is the number of bytes `instance_a` requires, even if some of the bytes are padding.  In general, there may or may not be storage for other objects located immediately adjacent, but the storage of unrelated objects will not overlap the storage of `instance_a`.  There *will* be storage for at least one object immediately adjacent if `instance_a` is a member of an array of 2 or more elements.